# JBPM workflow deployment into alfresco error

Tags: jboss, alfresco, jbpm

I'm getting the following error when deploying from JBPM eclipse interface to alfresco. This happens when I select 'classes and resources to include in process archive', like 'src/main/java' etc.

```
Exception happened while deploying
java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.jbpm.gd.jpdl.util.ProcessDeployer.addClassOrResource(Unknown Source)
```

It was working perfectly, just stopped working suddenly. Any clues?
Thanks.

Comment: Any exceptions or errors in Alfresco's tomcat log?

Comment: Error in eclipse's error log. reinstalled eclipse, same error. It doesn't even get to communicating with Alfresco's tomcat, so no logs there.

Comment: Which version of jBPM are you using?

Answer (score 2):

You should try not selecting anything in the Java Classes and Resources pane. You should be able to deploy your process definition XML file. If you have Java classes specific to your process definition, just have your build script JAR those up alongside your other Alfresco related Java classes you may have and put those in WEB-INF/lib.